# VSE/Compositor - Something similar to Turbulence Displacement effect in After Effects

Tags: compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor, effects

I'm experimenting with creating some video effects in Blender, and I was wondering if anyone knew how to create something similar to the Turbulence Displacement effect that After Effects has (It sort of stretches and distorts the image in a random way. An example image I found is bellow), in the VSE or the Compositor of Blender. I've tried messing around with different nodes/effect strips and can't seem to come up with anything. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible you could give an example of the kind of effect you're after? (not everyone knows what the turbulence effect from after effects is and won't want to take time to search)

Comment: Sure, I will edit my original post. Sorry I didn't give more of an explanation to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a *[Displace](http://blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/distort/displace.html)* node with a *[Clouds](http://blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/types/procedural/clouds.html)* procedural texture (in the compositor):

[image]

- The nodes in the "X Y scale" frame are just for convenience, you can also set the scale directly on the texture node.
- The mix node in the "Recenter" frame subtracts `.5` gray to keep the result in place; the displace node moves pixels up/right for positive numbers and down/left for negative numbers. To move pixels both ways, the `0..1` range of the texture needs to be shifted to `-.5..+.5`.

The scale inputs on the displace node itself set the distance (in pixels) a value of 1 in the vector input will move the corresponding pixel of the image input. In this example I set the vertical scale to 0 to mimic your reference image.