# Glass Distortion without the glass object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, compositing-nodes, glass

i need a glass distortion effect but without the object visible.
Is this possible?
Would be nice if this is possible to fake in compositing.

Thanks so far.

Comment: What kind of *glass distortion*?

Comment: something like that http://fabricated.io/blog/on-transparency

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40437/vse-compositor-something-similar-to-turbulence-displacement-effect-in-after-ef and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94248/chromatic-aberration-alpha-mask

Comment: that could be it. I will try it. 

Thank u so far!